# Why does Spring Boot actuator have dot separated prometheus metrics names?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus

I'm using Spring Boot with micrometer, but it appears the metric name format is incorrect.

Spring boot version `2.1.4.RELEASE`
and `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.3.5`

I get metrics back from `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus`

But the metric names have dots instead of underscores.

When using the `promtool` for linting, I get this error message back -

`error while linting: text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name in comment`

Example metric output -

```
# HELP tomcat.global.request.max  
# TYPE tomcat.global.request.max gauge
tomcat.global.request.max{environment="development",host="local",name="http-nio-8080",service="mobile_backend",} 0.0
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, or how I change the separator to underscores.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Looks fine locally with the same versions. Do you have any custom `NamingConvention` in place?

Comment: @mweirauch - you were right! There was a `NamingConvention` in the configuration. I just recently started working on this project, and didn't know there was a custom metric config. If you form your response into an Answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: See also standard available conventions in io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.NamingConvention

Comment: Oddly enough, I'd like to know how you got the dot separator in the first place, because that's what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you got no other `NamingConvention` implementation in place which replaces the original `PrometheusNamingConvention` for the `PrometheusMeterRegistry`.

Comment: Reference for curious: [NamingConvention.java](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/config/NamingConvention.java) interface and [PrometheusNamingConvention.java](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/implementations/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micrometer/prometheus/PrometheusNamingConvention.java#L47) class.